# How can i write the prometheus complex alerting rule in simplified manner?

Tags: alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

The expression of my alert rule is shown below , i need to write as many as 20 alert rules with same expression but the method_name and service_name varies from rule to rule making my alert.yaml file ugly can anyone specify simplified manner for writing these type of alerts

Expression:

```
( sum(rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_bucket{endpoint="http",grpc_method="MethodName",grpc_service="ServiceName",grpc_type="unary",job="JobName",le="1",service="ServiceName"}[15m])) by (job)+sum(rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_bucket{endpoint="http",grpc_method="MethodName",grpc_service="ServiceName",grpc_type="unary",job="JobName",le="5",service="ServiceName"}[15m])) by (job) ) / 2 /  sum(rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_count{endpoint="http",grpc_method="MethodName",grpc_service="ServiceName",grpc_type="unary",job="JobNAme",service="ServiceName"}[15m])) by (job) < 0.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alert on all *method_names* & *service_names* you can just skip adding these in label selector entirely

```
(
  (
    sum by (job) (rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_bucket{endpoint="http",grpc_type="unary",job="JobName",le="1",service="ServiceName"}[15m])) 
  +
    sum by (job) (rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_bucket{endpoint="http",grpc_type="unary",job="JobName",le="5",service="ServiceName"}[15m]))
  ) / 2 
/  
 sum by (job)(rate(grpc_server_handling_seconds_count{endpoint="http",grpc_type="unary",job="JobNAme",service="ServiceName"}[15m]))
) < 0.9
```

Otherwise you can use some templating tool like [ytt](https://get-ytt.io/) to generate the required rules for all different combinations of *method_names* & *service_names*

Comment: label "le"  changes for the each method name

Comment: Is it possible to generate an alert with the help of recording rules?

Comment: Not quite, due to the sum by job it'd combine them all together. You'd need to also add method name and service name to the by clause for this to work - which would be recommended in any case so that you'd have those as labels in your alerts.